# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: machine-learning, numpy

I was trying to print  the index  of each of the maximum probability of the probability
 Array, While Executing the following code I get the error

" The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

```
for prob_ in prob:
        max_prob=max(prob_)
        index=clf.classes_[prob.index(max(prob_))]
```

where the prob is an array

Comment: The error is for which line? is `prob` a numpy array?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: The error is in the last line "index=",prob is a numpy array

Comment: I guess you should change the last line to `index=clf.classes_[prob.index(max(prob))]`

Comment: same error appears

Comment: Consequently, I guess, something goes wrong with `clf.classes_` if you get the error from that line. Please notify me unless I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my code:

```
c = max(
[np.dot(theta[j], X[i]) for j in range(theta.shape[0])]
) / temp_parameter
```

I ran debugger and figured out that `theta[j], X[i]` were not the same shape, so dot product gave an ndarray instead of scalar as a result. `max()` function was a bit confused about it, because it does not work with ndarrays.
So, the conclusion is:

- if `prob_` is an ndarray, please, use `numpy.max()`, it should definitely work:

  `[In]: f = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])
  [In]: max(f)
  [Out]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
  [In]: np.max(f)
  [Out]: 2`
- if `prob_` is a list, check whether its components are scalars or lists:

  `[In]: f = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
  [In]: max(f)
  [Out]: [2, 2, 2]
  [In]: g = [numpy.array([1, 1, 1]), numpy.array([2, 2, 2])]
  [In]: max(g)
  [Out]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`